# Clarifications about the `decision_function_shape` parameter of SVC object from sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

### Question

The parameter `decision_function_shape` of the [`sklearn.svm.SVC`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) object seems not to be decisive at all on the output itself, but only reshaping the array of the score of each classifier. But is there any way to understand how the array is transformed in the basic implementation of the object (OvO strategy and `ovr` default argument for `decision_function_shape` ?

### Observations

SVC for multiclass classification is implemented to use a One vs One strategy. So we get *n-choose-2* classifiers for *n* class. So to recap :

```py
ovo = SVC()                                     # (n choose 2) classifiers
ovo_bis = SVC(decision_function_shape='ovo')    # (n choose 2) classifiers
ovr =  OneVsRestClassifier(SVC())               # n classifiers


ovo.decision_function([one_instance])           # return array of len n
ovo_bis.decision_function([one_instance])       # return array of len (n choose 2)
ovr.decision_function([one_instance])           # return array of len n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation from the collection of OvO classifiers to a OvR decision function happens in the function `_ovr_decision_function`, [source here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15a949460dbf19e5e196b8ef48f9712b72a3b3c3/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py#L423).  To summarize, each OvO classifier involving class `i` votes on whether each sample is of class `i`, and these votes are tallied and the class receiving the most votes wins; to break ties, the confidence level (OvO decision functions) is incorporated in, again being totaled among the OvO classifiers, and now scaled into a range appropriate for tie-breaking-only.